# Inappropriate Redis Database Design

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I have a node.js API that is responsible for 3 things:

- Registering a buyer
- Getting a buyer with ID
- Finding the matching buyer's offer based on some criteria

Details [here](https://github.com/dragify/challenge-buyer-router)

Since I'm new to Redis, I started the implementation like this:

1. JSON.stringify the buyer and store it with SET
2. Store all buyer's offers as ordered set (this is for the third endpoint, which requires the offer with the highest value) - this set contains string that represents the name of a hash
3. Then, that hash stores strings that represent the names of sets that have certain values and a location which the user will be redirected to after these conditions have been fulfilled (buyer1_devices, buyer1_hours, etc.)

Now, here is the problem:

I need to get GET /route working. As described on GitHub page that I have provided, I have 3 parameters: a timestamp, devices, and states. I have to browse through all the sets and get the appropriate location to redirect a user to. The location is stored in a hash, but I have to browse through all the sets. Since this is probably a bad implementation, where did it all go wrong and to go about implementing this?

- Note that this is a redis problem, not a node one. I need instructions on how to go about implementing this in Redis, and then I will be ready to code it in Node.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Wouldn't helping you complete a coding challenge be considered as facilitating cheating?

Comment: @ItamarHaber I am free to consult anybody, that's what they said. It is not a challenge, more of a entry problem for a job.

Comment: Okie dokey - ethics quenched, writing what I hope would be a helpful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first rule of Redis: store the data just like you want to read it.

To answer the `/route` query you need "filteration" on two attributes of from the buyers' offers - state and device. There is more than one way to skin that cat, so here's one: use many Sorted Sets for the offers.

Each such offers Sorted Set key name could look like this: `<device>:<state>` (so the example offered in the git will be added to the key `desktop:CA`).

To query, use the route's arguments to compose your key's name, then proceed regularly to find the highest-scored offer and resolve the buyer's details in the Hash.

Now go get that job!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. So, my design is poor as I thought it was. So it's okay to make a lot of sets? I come from relational databases, so this is very strange to me.

Comment: It is ok within reason - use your common sense ;) I also came from that path so I know what you mean. Second rule of Redis: denormalization isn't a dirty word (and in this case, you're not even doing that).